# PKCS8 Format RSA keygeneration

Tags: ios, swift, rsa, pkcs#1

```
    let attributes: CFDictionary =
                [kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, // 1
                 kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 2048, // 2
                 kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:
                 [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true, // 3
                 kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: 
                 kAsymmetricCryptoManagerApplicationTagPrivate ] // 4
                ] as CFDictionary


// Keypair Generation
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    do {
            guard SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes, &error) != nil else { // 
            throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
            }
            print("key created")
            } 
            catch {
                  print(error.localizedDescription)
            }      



    let query: CFDictionary = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey, //1
                               kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: 
                               kAsymmetricCryptoManagerApplicationTagPrivate, // 2
                               kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, //3
                               kSecReturnRef as String: true] as CFDictionary //4
    var item: CFTypeRef?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &item) //5
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
               print("keychain don't have private key")
               return
           }
   let privateKey = item as! SecKey
  
   guard let publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey), //1

   let data = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey, nil) else { //2
              return
      }
       guard SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(publicKey, .encrypt, .rsaEncryptionPKCS1) //3
    else {
           print("not supported cryptography")
           return
         }
    let finalData = data as Data //4

    print(finalData.base64EncodedString())

    print(finalData.base64EncodedString().utf8)

    }
```

The above code printing RSA Public key in below format(i.e in pkcs#1)

```
MIIBCgKCAQEAq5231ByJ2Mc9uNcGIWhnMudCUFfLzFtA+jyJNt+S/7Qyq1JDzp+Xq9HRdNV1NAdKBjE+/TUTbJqFSiZJ3qUwJS9TEgj9MYVDeeshXrD0n0eVt3BysWuov0Q2EwH7VbZ7Bpg4u8YmntZglSYAP0xOtAXf/N57iyJw7VVsyWMlH3udpxL/WI34gupD6NKDWCvSIYhfdt9EZFPiH3XpMUbVgUZcO0oeSPfYrQc+9ubgM+OSTO/zAOs5Ae7EZ1OufdZsyeLoG+COu+8gEPDz/1LYg/sGLHbP6BwQ8vAmvub2RWcoJoSemDuzWfd7EjG4qkZJkumtsBnCsQbNfo6bwlMjowIDAQAB
```

But i want to generate RSA Public key which will looks likes below (i.e PKCS#8)

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq5231ByJ2Mc9uNcGIWhnMudCUFfLzFtA+jyJNt+S/7Qyq1JDzp+Xq9HRdNV1NAdKBjE+/TUTbJqFSiZJ3qUwJS9TEgj9MYVDeeshXrD0n0eVt3BysWuov0Q2EwH7VbZ7Bpg4u8YmntZglSYAP0xOtAXf/N57iyJw7VVsyWMlH3udpxL/WI34gupD6NKDWCvSIYhfdt9EZFPiH3XpMUbVgUZcO0oeSPfYrQc+9ubgM+OSTO/zAOs5Ae7EZ1OufdZsyeLoG+COu+8gEPDz/1LYg/sGLHbP6BwQ8vAmvub2RWcoJoSemDuzWfd7EjG4qkZJkumtsBnCsQbNfo6bwlMjowIDAQAB
```

As per my knowledge the bolded text is the only difference between pcks#1 and pcks#8  publickey.
How to generate PKCS#8 public and private in IOS Swift?

---

Comment: You are **not** looking for PKCS#8 encoded public keys for the simple reason that PKCS#8 is specific to private keys. What you want is conversion from a PKCS#1 public key format in base 64 encoded DER to SubjectPublicKeyInfo (SPKI) to base 64 encoded DER. And yeah, I don't know how to do that in Swift... you could shell out some money for Chilkat (no affiliation).

Comment: Or you could try and create the additional SEQUENCE and OID yourself. Trick is to get the DER length encoding right. See [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq5231ByJ2Mc9uNcGIWhnMudCUFfLzFtA-jyJNt-S_7Qyq1JDzp-Xq9HRdNV1NAdKBjE-_TUTbJqFSiZJ3qUwJS9TEgj9MYVDeeshXrD0n0eVt3BysWuov0Q2EwH7VbZ7Bpg4u8YmntZglSYAP0xOtAXf_N57iyJw7VVsyWMlH3udpxL_WI34gupD6NKDWCvSIYhfdt9EZFPiH3XpMUbVgUZcO0oeSPfYrQc-9ubgM-OSTO_zAOs5Ae7EZ1OufdZsyeLoG-COu-8gEPDz_1LYg_sGLHbP6BwQ8vAmvub2RWcoJoSemDuzWfd7EjG4qkZJkumtsBnCsQbNfo6bwlMjowIDAQAB) for the SPKI structure.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank for reply sir. I'm converting publickey to exportableDER. please let me know should I export privatekey also to der for signing?